# Expansion of $ \left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right)^m$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, summation, symmetric-polynomials

What is the expansion of 
$
\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right)^m? 
$

For example, 
\begin{align*}
\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right)^2&=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2+2\sum_{i < j}^n x_ix_j,\\
\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right)^3&=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^3+3\sum_{i < j}^n x_i^2x_j +6\sum_{i < j < k}^n x_ix_jx_k.
\end{align*}
I suspect this is some well-known result but I could not find it. (sorry if the answer is just a link to a webpage)

Comment: [Multinomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem)

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle \big( \sum_{i=1}^{m} x_{i} \big)^{n} = \sum_{k_{1}+k_{2}+ \cdots + k_{n}=n} \binom{n}{k_{1}, k_{2}, \ldots, k_{n}} \displaystyle \Pi_{t=1}^{m}x_{t}^{k_{t}}$, where $\binom{n}{k_{1}, k_{2}, \ldots, k_{n}} = \frac{n!} {k_{1}! k_{2}! \cdots k_{n}!} $